# How to use 1 external port for 3 applications

Tags: wildfly, reverse-proxy, spring-cloud-gateway

I Have a 3 applications,

React Front using NextJs
Spring rest API
WildFly server

But so I only have one external port available, I can use some proxy or gateway to access my applications?

I saw Spring cloud Gateway, could run on my external port and redirecting the request for the correctly app? Or is there a better way?

Like this:

- Request ip:8433/app1 -> localhost:9000
- Request ip:8433/app2 -> localhost:9001
- Request ip:8433/app3 -> localhost:9002

Edit One, Spring cloud Gateway code:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("API", r -> r.path("/api/**").uri("http://localhost:8084"))
            .route("UI", r -> r.path("/ui/**").uri("http://localhost:3000"))
            .route("WILDFLY", r -> r.path("/wildfly/**").uri("https://localhost:8087/wildfly"))
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: What issues are you having with Spring Cloud Gateway?

Comment: To React and Spring Boot apps works fine. But when I access wildfly server, I'm redirect to localhost.

Comment: That is probably a config issue. Can you show your code/configs for the gateway, please?